# Unity 5.1 GUI very slow

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm writing a game and I was previously using PowerUI third party package to render some complicated "world Space" GUI using HTML.

I just spend days converting everything over to using the new gui system from unity that uses canvas, panels etc.

I was getting around 60 fps using PowerUI, now with the new unity gui system the frame rate dropped to less than 1 fps, or even less than 0.1fps, and this is without all the full game features running.

Its so slow now its completely useless.

Has anybody seen this problem?

This is pretty serious!!

How can it be fixed?

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: please include some of the GUI coding you have done

Comment: Run profiler on your scene and see what part of your ui is consuming cpu cycles.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid it's too late to answer.
I had the similar problem with Unity5.3.
I am using uGUI from Unity. On the scene, I have a scroll view that is a GameObject which has ScrollRect and Image as the components. 
And the scroll view has many children objects. At that time the performance was terribly poor.
I tried removing "Image" components as many as possible from the scroll view and the children except for the objects that really needs "Image" component. That improved the performance for my case.